# Maven: Why can I run mvn checkstyle:checkstyle without pom.xml config?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, checkstyle

I'm using a a basic maven project where only the following things are defined in pom.xml:

- dependency javaee-api
- dependency junit
- plugin maven-compile-plugin
- plugin maven-war-plugin
- plugin wildfly-maven-plugin

Why can I run `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` in the command window? Shouldn't I have to define the checkstyle plugin the `pom.xml`? What am I missing?

Edit: The eclipse plugin "Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-In" is installed. Is that the reason? If yes, how does maven communicate with it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you have already seen it is possible to execute plugins directly from the command line without configuring the plugin in your project's POM file.

To know which plugin you want to execute maven uses plugin prefix resolution.

Using your command line, `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle`, as an example this is roughly what maven does:

- take the prefix, the bit before the colon, from the execution. In your case `checkstyle`.
- resolve this to the possible name (artifactId) of a plugin. For this it uses two possible formats:

  - `maven-${prefix}-plugin` (for official Maven plugins)
  - `${prefix}-maven-plugin` (for plugins from other sources)
- so now it has `maven-checkstyle-plugin` as the artifactId of the plugin
- search for a plugin with this artifactId and one of the configured groupIds (by default maven searches using the groupId `org.apache.maven.plugins`)
- it finds the [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/dependency-info.html)
- executes the goal (the bit after the colon in the command), so the [checkstyle goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html) in this case.

All of this is explained in far more detail and better than I can at the [plugin prefix mapping](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) page of the official maven documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much - now I understand! Is there an advantage for defining it in the pom.xml over using it the way I did?

Comment: Glad the answer helped. The big advantage is that if you define it in the POM it will run at the appropriate time (the part of the lifecycle phase it is bound to) during every build of your module. If you don't configure it in the pom then you have to execute it manually every time.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that a plugin might not need to be explicitly configured in the pom nor to be bound to a phase to be run. And so, it can always be run by direct invocation (specifying the goal instead the phase when invoking to Maven):

```
mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
```

Look at the [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) documentation:

> A plugin goal represents a specific task (finer than a build phase) which contributes to the building and managing of a project. It may be bound to zero or more build phases. A goal not bound to any build phase could be executed outside of the build lifecycle by direct invocation.

It definitely has nothing to be with Eclipse plugins.